# Docker builder build vs docker build

Tags: docker

On Docker's documentation page, there's an entry for [docker builder](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder/) which is the parent command of [docker builder build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_build/). `docker builder build` seems like the exact same command as [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), and the documentations provides no information about it. Are they literally the same thing?

Comment: yeah it seems like the same thing to me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, currently they are behaving the same and `builder` is an [alias](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/cmd/docker/docker.go#L231). To understand why `builder` subcommand was presented, look at the [commit](https://github.com/docker/cli/commit/f597f2d026b7efe3fc55fa2b34bccd2d6b977063) message:

> Add new `builder` subcommand and implement `builder prune` to prune
>   build cache.
>
> This patch adds a new builder subcommand, allowing to add more
>   builder-related commands in the future. Unfortunately `build` expects
>   an argument so could not be used as a subcommand.
>
> This also implements `docker builder prune`, which is needed to prune
>   the builder cache manually without having to call `docker system prune`.
>
> Today when relying on the legacy builder, users are able to prune
>   dangling images (used as build cache) by running `docker image prune`.
>   This patch allows the same usecase with buildkit.