# What is the recommended command to build docker images

Tags: docker

There is [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), [docker image build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/), [docker builder build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/builder_build/). All seems to be doing the same thing.

> Build an image from a Dockerfile

Amazingly enough, none of them are legacy commands.

```
% DOCKER_HIDE_LEGACY_COMMANDS=1 docker --help | grep build
  builder     Manage builds
  build       Build an image from a Dockerfile

% DOCKER_HIDE_LEGACY_COMMANDS=1 docker builder --help | grep build
Usage:  docker builder COMMAND
Manage builds
  build       Build an image from a Dockerfile

% DOCKER_HIDE_LEGACY_COMMANDS=1 docker image --help | grep build
  build       Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Which one is the latest. Which one is the recommended command.

Comment: I’ve always used docker build. First time I’m hearing about the other two.

Comment: AFAICT, they are the result of restructuring the Docker CLI in an effort to simplify documentation and tab-completion, which involved introducing new subcommands. However, they kept (some of the(?)) the original commands, too, such as `docker build`. https://www.docker.com/blog/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547778/docker-builder-build-vs-docker-build

Comment: AFAIK, `docker build` is an alias to `docker image build` and `docker builder build`. All 3 can be used interchangeably.